# How many town ordinances can I enact at a time?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*, how many town ordinances can I enact concurrently? (I figure the early/late ordinances would conflict, but what about the others?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're only able to have one ordinance active at a time (which I believe Isabelle states when you unlock the ability). They cost 20,000 bells to enact, and they do not go into effect until the day after you enact them.